# Fixing try/catch, and output

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am adding an OU of users to a group, and want to capture:

1. Users added
2. Users already on the list
3. output the above to a file

The current code below works and outputs:

```
UserName              GroupName                          TimeStamp
--------              ---------                          ---------
%Username%            %groupname%                        14/10/2019 15:50:49
```

But, the `catch` doesn't catch users already in the group and report on output on console. The export to CSV just contains all users in the OU and shows what time it added.

I would like the `catch` output to trigger on screen, and have some way in the exported CSV file to show if a user was already added or was added on this run.

The code that I'm using:

```
$groupName = 'SOMEGROUP'
$ou = 'OU=Users,DC=DC,DC=LOCAL'
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential bsg\myusername$

$results = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Credential $cred | ForEach-Object {
    #Add the user to the group here
    $userName = $_.Name
    try {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Members $_.DistinguishedName -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop
    } catch {
        Write-Warning "User $userName is already a member of group $groupName"
    }

    # output a PsCustomObject that gets collected in the $results variable
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'UserName'  = $userName
        'GroupName' = $groupName
        'TimeStamp' = Get-Date
    }
}

# output on console
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Export to CSV file
$results | Export-Csv C:\PS\AddADGroupToUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

I'm not sure about the `Add-ADGroupMember`. Does it matter it's DistingushedName there rather than maybe `$userName`?

I'd like the output to show me the `catch` which isn't working.

I have used `-Credential $cred` on both statements, is there an easier way to make everything run as `-Credential` as a session rather than the commands for neatness?

---

Replies read and understood. 
I ran the script. Users are already in the group so I expected them all to come back as "user is already a member of group …." but instead it seems to error.

Error message after latest update (the group already had a lot of members in):

```
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Members'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the
argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try the
command again.
At C:\PS\add to usersNEW2.ps1:28 char:57
+ ... oupMember -Identity $groupName -Members $_.DistinghuishedName -ErrorA ...
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGrou
   pMember
```

Output CSV is incorrect, as users weren't added, they were already in it. So results are wrong:

```
UserName    GroupName   TimeStamp           Status
TheUser     GROUPSActual    16/10/2019 15:23    User added successfully
```

So moving away from Theo's code, I've tried Ivan's suggestion but this is taking a LONG time:

```
# I'll use the DistinghuishedName because this is always unique in the forest
$currentMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinghuishedName

$results = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -credential $cred | ForEach-Object {

    # test if the user is already a member by checking the array

If ((Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname).distinguishedName -contains $_.distinguishedName) {
    Write-Warning "User $userName is already a member of group $groupName"
}
else { 
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Members $_.DistinguishedName -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop
}
        # output a PsCustomObject that gets collected in the $results variable
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'UserName'  = $_.Name
            'GroupName' = $groupName
            'TimeStamp' = Get-Date
            'Status'    = $status
    }
}
```

It's working I think, but has taken several minutes to get 3 results out of 7, whereas original code worked in seconds.
Edit: Code has finished, and has written to host the warning. I know I can tweak the status part to add the error to status. Just shouldn't take so long!

Timestamps were seconds apart, but now:

```
TimeStamp
16/10/2019 16:12
16/10/2019 16:14
16/10/2019 16:15
16/10/2019 16:16
16/10/2019 16:17
16/10/2019 16:18
16/10/2019 16:19
```

Answer (score 3):

The `catch` block is executed only when an error occurs while the `ErrorAction` is set to `Stop`. `Add-ADGroupMember` does not return an error when the user is already member of the group.

I would suggest to use some kind of logic in your script in the try block. Something like:

```
If ((Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname).distinguishedName -contains $_.distinguishedName) {
    Write-Warning "User $userName is already a member of group $groupName"
}
else { 
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Members $_.DistinguishedName -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

Still you may use the `catch` block to handle any errors that could occur.

Comment: You may want to force the `if` condition to be evaluated as an array: `@((Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname).distinguishedName)` to handle the case where there is only one member of the group.

Comment: You should receive `Add-AdGroupMember : The specified account name is already a member of the group` exception. What OS are you using?

Comment: @Theo In my lab environment, I was not able to reproduce any exception message, but I was abel to run the command multiple times `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity group01 -Members test01` with no error being displayed or stored into the `$Error` variable.

Comment: Correct, in that I do not get an exception message in my environment if I run the code multiple times

Comment: I've tried to use the code above, along with the original command of `$currentMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinghuishedName`. But the script takes forever, is your code running the get-adgroupmember command again? The original code (whilst it doesn't report the fails for members already added) took seconds. Now the code takes minutes. It seems to be working, but out of 7 users, it's 10 minutes in and has successfully only caught 2 are a member already but still running

Comment: A couple of hints:
1. Why using `Select-Object`? When piping, you are addressing obejcts sequentially which is much slower.  I would suggest to try with the provided example: `(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname).distinguishedName`
2. If you would like to find out where the script is slow you may try two approaches: 
2.1 Use debugging, running line by line and identify on which command it is performing not as expected and investigate
2.2. Use `Measure-Command` on the commands suspected of executing slow or whole blocks. It would show the time for execution of each and again investigate

Answer (score 0):

Although I have never seen the `Add-ADGroupMember` **NOT** throwing exception `Add-AdGroupMember : The specified account name is already a member of the group` before, [Ivan MIrchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12009086/ivan-mirchev) reports that in his environment there is no exception whatsoever when trying to add a user that is already a member of the group.

If that is really the case in some environments, then trusting on that exception is no longer a good idea and we need to take an extra step by first getting an list of all current members of the group.
This extra step will of course lead to longer processing time..

```
# Get all user objects s that are currently member of the group and capture only 
# the usable property like SamAccountName or DistinghuishedName to use for the -Members 
# parameter of Add-ADGroupMember.
# the -Members parameter takes either:
#   the DistinghuishedName
#   the ObjectGUID
#   the SID
#   the SamAccountName

# Use a Hasttable object for fast lookup
$currentMembers = @{}
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } | ForEach-Object {
    # you could also use the SamAccountName, but they are only unique within the same domain.
    # I'll use the DistinghuishedName because this is always unique in the forest
    # the Value of the entry is not important, we'll only use the Key.
    $currentMembers[$_.DistinghuishedName] = $true
}

$results = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou | ForEach-Object {
    # test if the user is already a member by checking if the lookup Hashtable has that Key
    $userName = $_.Name
    if ($currentMembers.ContainsKey($_.DistinghuishedName)) {
        Write-Host "User $userName is already a member of group $groupName"
        $status = "User $userName is already a member"
    }
    else {
        try {
            # the user is not already a member, so add him/her to the group
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Members $_.DistinghuishedName -ErrorAction Stop
            $status = "User $userName added successfully"
        }
        catch {
            # something went wrong..
            $status = "User $userName could not be added to group $groupName. Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }

    # output a PsCustomObject that gets collected in the $results variable
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'UserName'  = $userName
        'GroupName' = $groupName
        'TimeStamp' = Get-Date
        'Status'    = $status
    }
}
# output on console
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Export to CSV file
$results | Export-Csv C:\PS\AddADGroupToUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: this didn't work. I've edited my original post to show the error and that the output is wrong.

Comment: FYI I tried the different code above also, and that works perfectly but takes a LONG time rather than your code that took seconds. I don't know how to speed it up.

Comment: @RobPowell you might be able to speed up a little by creating a hash table for $currentMembers instead of an array and check if each user DN is a key in that hash. The code that relies on an exception is WAY faster of course. I'm on mobile now. Will add code for the lookup hashtable tomorrow so you can test it out.

Comment: @RobPowell I have edited my answer to now use a (faster) lookup Hashtable object. This should improve the processing speed. For any other errors the `Add-ADGroupMember` can throw I have inserted a `try{..} catch{..}` block.

Comment: This ran for 7 minutes, and couldn't find anything. So script ran, no output to host, and it created an empty .csv. I am tempted to give up and just accept a cheap and dirty add without verification

Comment: @RobPowell Then I suggest you really have a critical look at what is in your `$groupName` (should be DistinghuishedName or objectGUID or SID or SamAccountName). Also check if the SearchBase `$ou` is a valid DistinghuishedName for the OU you are querying. Add some `Write-Host` messages to see whether you are really getting any users from the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet.